# i'm working on a listview but i keep getting an error saying "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean ... on a null object reference"

Tags: android-studio

//this code is in a SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
boolean addphone (String p_name,String P_desc,String price){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2,p_name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,P_desc);
        contentValues.put(COL4,price);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        return true;}
```

//this is how i called it on MainActivity

```
if(newPname.length() != 0 && newPdesc.length() != 0 && newPrice.length() != 0){
                    myDB.addphone(newPname,newPdesc,newPrice);
                    et_name.setText("");
                    et_desc.setText("");
                    et_price.setText("");}
```

//also had this on the same class

```
boolean addphone(String newPname,String p_desc,String p_price){
   myDB.addphone(newPname, p_desc, p_price);
    return true;
  

}
```

Comment: Can you indicate what line the error is happening on?

Comment: it happens on this line: myDB.addphone(newPname,newPdesc,newPrice);

Comment: It could be a lot of things, but is there a reason you're returning a boolean that is hard coded to be true?  Seems like these functions could change to void. I don't see you using any other booleans here so it must be something to do with that.

Comment: i was following a tutorial on making a customAdapter for a list that contains multiple views from a sqliteopenhelper. but nothing seems to work. when i add an item, the emulator crashes every time.